# how to remove $Id property from a list?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a list in my back end code(MVC), when i access the data by using an api, in my list i can see a property named $id has been appended. i dont want this to be happen. what should i do?

This is my list:

```
var IList<sponsor> result=getSponser(id); 
return this.ok(result)
```

when access this from api(angualrjs) using action method in the controller.
output is:

```
{
"$id":"2",
"Sponsor":
    {
      "$id":"3",
      "Id":3,
      "Name":"testing sponsor",
      "LogoPath":null,
      "Address":null,
      "ContactNumber":null,
      "Country":null
    },
"User":
    {
      "$id":"4",
      "Id":7031,
      "UserName":"priteshabc",
      "IsActive":true,
      "CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "LastLoginDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "RoleId":2,
      "Password":null,
      "IsPasswordChanged":false
    },
"Id":1026,
"UserName":null,
"FullName":"asdfasdf",
"FirstName":null,
"LastName":null,
"Email":"pretsh@aksdf.asdff",
"Countries":
    [
        {"$id":"1","Id":1,"Name":"Afghanistan","Code":"AF"},
        {"$id":"4","Id":4,"Name":"American Samoa","Code":"AS"},
        {"$id":"7","Id":7,"Name":"Anguilla","Code":"AI"},
        {"$id":"9","Id":9,"Name":"Antigua and Barbuda","Code":"AG"},
        {"$id":"10","Id":10,"Name":"Argentina","Code":"AR"}
    ],
 "Country":null,
 "PhoneNumber":"1354535151581",
 "IsActive":null,
 "Address":"asdfasdf"
```

}

You can see sponsors and user and country objects have a property called $id. i need to remove this from the C# level itself. What to do?

Comment: remove `$id` from your C#  class

Comment: its auto generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got the answer. previously i was doing

```
      return this.ok(result)   //=>this will cause generating $id property automatically in result of the get method(api side)
```

I was having an issue in model state validation in post method when I was having $id in the data i send(only oif there is same $id for different objects)

so  I replaced it with

```
            return json(result)
```

Comment: It is worth noting too that you need to return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: where were you when i posted this question @jomsk1e ?
i got the solution when nobody replied. now you are saying this one?